# Java - How can I avoid re-using a variable that represents a computation created in a loop that needs to be added to a list?

Tags: java, loops, variables

Alternative question: How can I re-use a variable without the value of the first use (that has been added to a list) being changed?

Instead of a long explanation, I'll just post some code, which should explain what I'm trying to do and demonstrate my problem.

```
public class Test
{
    static ArrayList<Double> totallist = new ArrayList<Double>();
    static ArrayList<Double> inputlist = new ArrayList<Double>();
    static ArrayList<ArrayList<Double>> outputlist = new ArrayList<ArrayList<Double>>(); //ArrayList of Arraylists
    static double total;

    public void test()
    {
            //the numbers aren't important, just examples
            inputlist.add(5);
            inputlist.add(3.8);
            inputlist.add(1.9);
            inputlist.add(.8);
            inputlist.add(4.1);

            outputlist.get(0).add(9);
            outputlist.get(0).add(5.9);
            outputlist.get(0).add(4);
            outputlist.get(0).add(2.88);
            outputlist.get(0).add(5.6);
            outputlist.get(1).add(3);
            //...etc until outputlist has 5 ArrayLists each with 5 doubles

            //I need to multiply each of the 5 inputs by each output in each      
            //internal ArrayList and then enter the sum of those
            //multiplications into totallist

            for (int i = 0; i < 5; i++) {
                total = 0;
                for (int i2 = 0; i2 < 5; i2++) {
                    double input = inputlist.get(i);
                    double output = outputlist.get(i).get(i2);
                    total += input * output;
                }
                totallist.add(total);
            }

            }
        }
```

As you can see, the problem is the variable `total`, which is getting reset each time the first for loop iterates. So the end result of the ArrayList `totallist` is 5 entries of the last i loop iteration instead of 5 entries of the result of each i loop iteration.

I can't figure out a way around this that doesn't involve a huge amount of variables and loops... There has to be something I'm missing.

Comment: Don't declare the variable as a `static` variable. Just declare a local variable.

Comment: I'm sure you mean `ArrayList<ArrayList<Double>>` rather than `ArrayList<ArrayList><Double>>`.

Comment: Andy - yes, that was just a typo - thanks (and fixed).

Comment: What is keeping you from initializing the total outside of the first loop? I'm probably missing something

Comment: If I declare `double total +=...` inside the for loop I can't add it to `totallist` outside of the loop though.

Comment: Nobody said to declare it inside the `for` loop, and the syntax in your comment doesn't even compile. Please format your code properly.

Comment: @jdfinch3 I don't understand what you mean by that. You said yourself that each time your first loop iterates your total value is reset to 0. To avoid this, move it outside of the loop. `double total +=...` does not change.

Comment: Thank you for the quick help everyone! The problem lied in my mis-understanding of how auto-boxing worked which caused me to look in the wrong place for the error in my actual code. Now that I know how this works I see the real problem. ...learn something new every day!

Answer (score 2, accepted):

There is no problem here to solve. The `total` variable gets auto-boxed to a `Double` object before being added to the list. You can reuse `total` to your heart's content.

However it should certainly be a local variable, not static.

Comment: Wait...this is new information for me. I understand what auto-boxing is but I don't understand why that allows `total` to be re-used. Can you please clarify? (I learned Java on my own, so there are some gaps in my knowledge...obviously...).

Comment: `total` is not added to the list. An auto-boxed `Double` having the same value as at that moment is added to the list. Your problem lies elsewhere.

Comment: Whoa, ok I see what you are saying now. Well...that changes everything. I knew the "problem" i was having had to be that I was missing something because it just didn't make sense. I guess I didn't understand auto-boxing as well as I thought I did.

I see where the problem in my actual code is coming from now, based on that - Thank you!